# Calling CGI python script as root from a web form

Tags: apache-2.2, python, cgi

I'm having difficulty getting a web form to run a CGI script that needs to perform a command with root permission. The form is:

```
<form class="mainform" action="./py/print_msg.py" method="POST">
    <textarea name="post" cols=70 rows=20></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Print" class="button">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="button">
</form>
```

The python script **print_msg.py** is executable (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root`) and a version that just prints strings to the browser work ok, so apache's CGI settings seems ok.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Adafruit_Thermal import *

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/ttyAMA0", 19200, timeout=5)
printer.wake()
time.sleep(1)
print "test"
printer.sleep()
```

This works when root runs it.  I've edited `/etc/sudoers` as follows:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u root /home/pi/www/html/py/print_msg.py
```

Not sure if this means www-data can run that script as root or if it will do so without needing to invoke `sudo`?  Now when I call the page I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/py/print_msg.py", line 7, in <module>
    printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/ttyAMA0", 19200, timeout=5)
  File "/home/pi/www/html/py/Adafruit_Thermal.py", line 73, in __init__
    Serial.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'
[Wed Jun 01 13:50:04.383712 2016] [cgid:error] [pid 30345:tid 2993681456] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.1.158:51239] AH02550: Failed to flush CGI output to client, referer: http://192.168.1.174/
```

Do I not have the right sudoers line perhaps?  Grateful for assistance.

Comment: `su` to `www-data` and find out if it can run it with sudo? If `www-data` is not allowed a shell you might not be able to execute anything

Comment: Changing `sudoers` won't help, because Apache doesn't use `sudo` to start the CGI process. Instead, you should give the `/dev/ttyAMA0` device file permissions that allow the `www-data` user to access it directly.

Comment: @Recct I tried that, but I got prompted for a www-data password, and I'm not sure if it's safe to set one..?

Comment: @MosheKatz OK I added www-data to group tty, and chmod 660 ttyAMA0 (from 600).  Well it works, but is it a safe thing to do?

Comment: @geotheory It's **much** safer than having the CGI script run as root.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to request root access each time you need to install this: https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Adafruit_Thermal import *

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/ttyAMA0", 19200, timeout=5)
printer.wake()
time.sleep(1)
print "test"
printer.sleep()
```

1. Cross domain ?
2. **Can't pause `CGI` out !** (0.1 second delay will be corrupted your data)

Like this :

```
import cgi # Maybe need form value etc.
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

myVar = "Failed : "
def myHandler(myVar = myVar):
    try :
        #Do stuf here !
        myVar = myContent

    except Exception,e :
        myVar += str(e)

myHandler()#we don't need any arguments !

print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8;" # What is your ContentType ?
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"
print
print myVar
```

**This is the basic flowchart (do not use it in this way without securing it)**